# select and separate results by group

Tags: mysql, node.js

i have an mysql table as below

| name | id | action |
| --- | --- | --- |
| usr1 | 1 | enroll |
| usr1 | 1 | view |
| usr1 | 1 | update |
| usr1 | 1 | delete |
| usr2 | 2 | enroll |
| usr2 | 2 | update |
| usr2 | 2 | view |
| usr2 | 2 | delete |

in nodejs, i am trying to select all from the above table, and group the results based on id column

1:
enroll, view, update, delete

2:
enroll, update, view, delete

can this be done using queries ?

Comment: edit question to include expected output'

Comment: No. Not with the present schema. Rows in relational databases represent unordered sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown how you get the order you show.  Assuming there's some other column that produces the order you want you would do:

```
select id, group_concat(action order by sort_column) as actions
from mystery_table_name
group by id
```